# Remove curly brackets when it presents ideally

Tags: lua

How do I remove curly brackets when there is no content before them?
For example, for this case "`{3.1} & {3.6} & {}`" I want curly braces to be removed and output like "`3.1 & 3.6 &` ".
And for this case curly braces has to be retained as it is like: "`\TH{1}{Paramaters} & \TH{1}{Values} & \TH{1}{Descriptions}\\` ".

Advance thanks.

**Input**:

```
\table{\begin{table}{T1}{%
\caption{Table 1.}%
\begin{tabular}{lll}\hline
\TH{1}{Paramaters} & \TH{1}{Values} & \TH{1}{Descriptions}\\ 
\hline
 {3.1} & {3.6} & {}\\
{4.1} & {4.6} & {}\\
{} & {5.6} & {}\\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
}\end{table}}
```

**Required Output**:

```
\table{\begin{table}{T1}{%
\caption{Table 1.}%
\begin{tabular}{lll}\hline
\TH{1}{Paramaters} & \TH{1}{Values} & \TH{1}{Descriptions}\\ 
\hline
 3.1 & 3.6 & \\
4.1 & 4.6 & \\
 & 5.6 & \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
}\end{table}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In other words: if a non-space symbol precedes a `{` then preserve the braces, otherwise remove them.

```
text = text:gsub("%f[%S]{(.-)}", "%1")
```

Comment: I would propose `text:gsub("%f[%S]%b{}", function(s) return s:sub(2, -2) end)` to support nested LaTeX commands inside the braces. Of course that would again fall short of escaped braces...